# WPF HwndHost и окно WPF - правильный фокус элемента

Tags: c#, winapi, wpf

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть проблема с созданием своего компонента через HwndHost. Так получается, что я не могу использовать WindowsFormsHost ввиду многопоточности приложения. Если кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно отключить перевод фокуса с HwndHost на окно WPF, чтобы фокус не сбрасывался с моего компонента, а оставался на нем при нажатии на окно WPF. В интернете видел обходной путь, но он состоял в том, что после снятия фокуса он затем возвращался назад (но это мне не подходит, так как он сбрасывает режим моего компонента (браузера) ). Вот нагдядно, что происходит:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось куда запутаннее. Я по примеру помещал нужный компонент в специально созданное через winapi окно. Чтобы добиться нужного поведения, я устанавливал различные функции и атрибуты, но ничего не помогало. Когда я нашел более удачный пример (где этого вообще не нужно было делать), я установил хостом сам компонент. Также для предотвращения снятия фокуса я не забыл установить на элементе `WPF  IsFocusable = False`.

З.Ы. Уже теперь мой компонент на уровень лучше родного WPF WebBrowser, хотя и имеет несколько строчек кода).